# Predicting Bank of Canada Future Rate Changes Based on 3-month CORRA Futures

Tags: futures, probability, central-banking

Earlier I asked a general question about how probabilities are derived from futures prices for derivatives related to the Bank of Canada's policy rate.

I have been advised the Overnight Index Swaps (OIS) are the best vehicle to use, in this case three month CORRA futures.

[3-month CORRA futures](https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/quotes?symbol=cra*#quotes) are traded on the Montreal Exchange.

The Exchange gives an [example](https://www.m-x.ca/f_publications_en/strategyCRA2_en.pdf) of calculating the probability of a rate change based on these future prices.

In the example, the prediction is made from only 12 days away.
Suppose we are six months away with a few BoC announcements between "today" and the BoC announcement we care about.

One of the terms in the example is described as:

```
Current geometric average since last announcement
(and expected to remain constant until the BoC announcement)
```

How can this be calculated when the rates that are required to calculate the geometric average are not known exactly, but are predicted with a certain probability?

Comment: I asked that general question earlier. Now I have a much more specific question dealing with 3-month CORRA futures and inputs into the probability calculation.

Comment: A future is not an OIS swap. You can look [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/71805/54838) for an example with futures.